# Are migrations really needed in NodeJS Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, database, model, sequelize.js, database-migration

In Sequelize, when we create a model using the following command,

```
sequelize model:generate --name Company --attributes name:string, desc:text
```

A migration file is also getting created. And we can make the models sync with the DB by adding the following piece of code.

```
models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    console.log("DB Synced");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Therefore, when there's a change in the column names or something, they get synced with the DB.

So, do we really need to run migration ? At any point in the development or production ?

Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Updating sequelize model requires to have the update applied to the DB too. How do you plan to have the DB updated otherwise? For example, il you add a column "Company" in your model, you want the DB to have the column too. Either you add it manually in your DB (bad practice) or you version DB modifications with migration files applying it, for example here, with `sequelize.sync()`

Comment: @DamienLeroux in that case I can create a separate migration for adding that column. Is that valid ?

Comment: No it's not mandatory to create migration, I works since a long time on a big app, I don't use the native way to do migration. You can create your model without the cli, and manage it via the way you want...

Comment: @TharinduLucky Yes It is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use explicit migrations and to point tables for storing applied migrations and seeds in a sequelize config in case you have different versions of a database in different production environments (even if you are just planning different production deployments).
If you run a newer version of your app with some model changes on an older production DB then by executing **sync** method you change this production DB accidentally. Moreover you cannot reverse these changes easily because you don't know anything about differences between models in your current app and tables in the production DB.

Comment: So, DB sync is not necessarily required to be addes in the app.js right?

Comment: Yes. You can apply all unapplied migrations and seeds by executing sequelize db:migrate and sequelize db:seed:all